# Why database config do not work?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I cloned a repo from github, and when I tried running `rake db:create`, shell shown me an error

```
ruby-2.2.0 ~/ymh (milestone3*) [02:47:02]
weare138$ rake db:create
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"development", "username"=>"root", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "pool"=>5, "port"=>3306, "password"=>"password", "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
```

There is database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: development
  username: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  port: 3306
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

where I am wrong?How to fix it?

*update*

```
ruby-2.2.0 ~/ymh (milestone3*) [02:47:38]
weare138$ rake --trace db:create
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"development", "username"=>"root", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "pool"=>5, "port"=>3306, "password"=>"password", "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
```

Comment: are you using ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Run `rake --trace db:create` and provide output. It should help to investigate your problem.

Comment: **shrikant1712** yes, I use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: check on console `mysql -u root -p` with your password

Comment: **maxd** I was updated question

Comment: **Sontya** `weare138$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure your that your mysql.sock is correct.
In ubuntu 14.04 it is located in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

So modified database.yml file will look like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: development
  username: root
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  port: 3306
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: thank u, but this is not solved.I think problem in the password, a default password for root user in mysql?

Comment: @vveare138 one important thing are you able to login to mysql using provided credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify the `pool` nor `socket` if you have a regular `mysql` package installation in your system (with `apt-get install` I mean).

Try to get rid of those.